# Is there a chemical compound which does not have a liquid state but a solid and a gaseous state?

Tags: phase, solid-state-chemistry, gas-phase-chemistry

Is there a chemical compound which does not have a liquid state but a solid and a gaseous state? Meaning no matter the temperature or pressure it will never be in its liquid form. According to my rather basic knowledge
of chemistry this means that it has a critical temperature  lower than the melting point.

I have seen [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/108795/126720) already, but it only talks about elements and not compounds.

Comment: Lots of them. They decompose on heating before they would melt, like hydrate salts, most hydroxides and carbonates, etc.

Comment: @OscarLanzi I updated the question. I meant things that have solid and gaseous forms but no liquid forms

Comment: Most organic compounds decompose before melting. So is there many unstable inorganic compounds, that decompose if the frost is not deep enough, or before reaching melting point.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31050/can-you-melt-wood https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/62539/why-don-t-all-objects-melt-and-liquefy-when-heated-sufficiently

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/94003/what-are-some-examples-of-pure-substances-with-no-liquid-state

Comment: Neither of these actually answer the question if any of these compounds have a solid & and a gaseous state but no liquid state, as they decompose before they would be either gaseous or liquid. So no these do not actually answer my question. @Mithoron

Comment: That still has nothing to do with any critical points, only chemical reaction.

Comment: Then my rather basic chemical knowledge was just plain wrong :D

Comment: It could be summarized that compounds with sufficient thermal and chemical stability do have their liquid phase, if there is high enough pressure available. A special case is [liquid carbon](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6068/what-is-known-about-liquid-carbon), where 100-1000 atm at 4500-5000 K is needed.

Comment: .....uhh, naphthalene

Comment: @NilayGhosh Only if sealed piece of naphtalene wouldn't melt because of decomposition.